# How to import bulk url rewrites in magento 2 using sql query

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I have Url rewrite excel sheet with request path, target path and redirect type. How can i add this values into url_rewrite table in magento 2 by running sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like Navicat to connect and import data directly to urlrewrite database and use the module https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites to regenerate them.